# Create Bad Words Filter

Tags: php

Hi please help me I am using this code to filter some words but the the problem is it doesn't match the exact word and in stead it just blocks words that contain the letters from my word.

For example: ".com" I type commander and the word gets blocked please help.

```
$badwords = explode('|', 'http|www|.com');
    foreach($badwords as $badword)
    {

        if(preg_match("/$badword/", $post->data['message'], $match))
        {

            $post->errors['badwords']['error_code'] = "Warning message goes here";

        }
    }
```

Comment: [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: Have a look at this answer on SO, which is what I used in the past http://stackoverflow.com/a/15552300/1415724

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you want is likely

```
preg_match("/\b$badword\b/i", $post->data['message'], $match))
```

The `\b` indicates a letter which cannot be used to form a word (see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)). This prevents `com` from matching `commander` or `datacom`. The `i` at the end makes the search case-insensitive.

Also, keep in mind that using `.com` as one of your badwords may not have the effect you want. The period character (`.`) matches *any* single character in a regular expression. Rather, you want to search for (`\.`), which will actually match the period. (See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) for more details on the period character.)

Finally, if you're trying to match URL's, you could check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904482/match-url-pattern-in-php-using-regular-expression).

Comment: your regex is correct but (and correct me if I am being thick) won't your strpos function pick any word CONTAINING that phrase?? this could be tricky if tit was added to bad words list - then it would block titan, stitch etc.?

Comment: no probs sweety - better explanation of regexes than mine :-P

Comment: preg_match("/\b$badword\b/i", $post->data['message'], $match)) if working fine thanks very much I love you

Comment: P.S. What I am trying to do id to block people from posting URL so how can I do that?

Comment: @user3065884, I suggest you post those as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

For words (and I mean words not .com etc) this is simple

You just want to pregmatch

```
'/\b' . $badword . '\b/'
```

\b is a word boundary

for full stops you must escape them . to mean them literally (without \ they actually mean and character in a regex) so I would either write a function that looks for full stops and then adds a \ before them or just add them straight into your list with the \ already appended.